# How should I store this data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a golf scoring program using python 3 which, for each of the 18 holes stores:
the hole number, the par, the difficulty rank, and the target score.

The target score is calculated from the par, difficulty, and handicap (which may be changed by the user).

What would you advise to be the best method for storing this data so that it can be displayed in a table-like fashion, and the target score easily changed if the user edits the value of the handicap?

I don't really know where to start as I have very little experience.

Thanks.

Comment: Or a `collections.namedtuple`!

Comment: How long are you storing it? If you only need to keep the data around until the user exits a dictionary would probably be best. If you need to keep it around for a while a database would be the best option.

Comment: Actually if the target score is purely calculated, you should probably just build a class for a score.

Comment: Yes, the data needs to be stored for a long time. Thank you, I will have a look into using a database.

Comment: to expand on @IanAuld and Alex Thornton's comments: if the par/difficulty/handicap data never changes (it is 'constant'), store it in the code of the program itself, as a dict or a list of tuples as Alex suggested. If the data changes as a result of running the program but still should persist until next time you run, then a database is useful. Python comes with SQLite support. You could also just use a text file, eg https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a class.

```
class HoleScore(object):
    def __init__(self, hole_number, par, difficulty, handicap=0):
        self.hole_number = hole_number
        self.par = par
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        self.handicap = handicap
    @property
    def target_score(self):
        return do_some_calculation_of_attributes(self.par, self.difficulty, self.handicap)
```

Then you can add a few dunder methods to help things along, or (better) design a function to build a table from a bunch of `HoleScore` objects. Something like:

```
# inside class HoleScore
    @staticmethod
    def make_table(list_of_holes):
        """list_of_holes is a list of HoleScore objects"""
        print("Some | headers | here")
        for hole in list_of_holes:
            fields = [hole.hole_number,
                      hole.par,
                      hole.handicap,
                      hole.target_score]
            print("|".join(fields)) # use some string formatting here?
```

Comment: So would I have to make 18 classes - 1 for each hole?

Comment: @Oceanescence No just 18 objects, e.g. `holes = [HoleScore(1, 4, 5), HoleScore(2, 6, 8)]` etc